# AngularJS - Executing dynamically created JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am calling a web service that returns a string that is a block of JavaScript.  I don't know anything about the JavaScript other than it has a well known entry point (`function doCalc(input)`) and a well known output (array of objects).  `doCalc` my call other functions that are also returned in the same string.

For example, the JavaScript string may look like this (simplified, but you get the idea):

```
function doCalc(input) {
   return calcPart1();
}
function calcPart1() {
    var output;
    // ...do something complicated
    calcPart2(output);
    return output;
}
function calcPart2() {
    return something;
}
```

I have this block of JavaScript as a string and I need to inject it on the page and call it every time the value of a textbox changes.  "input" is the value of the textbox.

I can do this by dynamically creating a script element and appending it to the body, but then `doCalc` is not accessible from my controller.  I would also like the output (array of objects) to be accessible in the controller and would like to bind to it using ngRepeat.

What is the most Angular-friendly way of handling a situation like this?

**Update**

I have 2 solutions now, but I don't really feel great about either one...

**Solution 1:** Inject the script into the DOM, call it from "onkeyup" and populate a hidden textarea that is bound to a controller variable. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7sb79pmh/)

```
// In the controller - Download the JavaScript code and inject it into the DOM
// this string would really come as the result of an web service call
$scope.javascriptCode = "function doCalc(input) { ... }";
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.innerHTML = $scope.javascriptCode;
document.body.appendChild(script);

<!-- In the view -->
<!-- Every time the input changes (onkeyup), set the text of a hidden textarea -->
<!-- that is bound to a variable in the controller -->
<input ng-model="scopeInput" onkeyup="handleChange(this.value);" />
<textarea id="outputText" ng-model="myOutput" style="display:none"></textarea>
<script>
    function handleChange(val) {
        var element = document.getElementById('outputText');
        element.value = doCalc(val);
        var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        evt.initEvent("input", false, true);
        element.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
</script>
```

**Solution 2** (with input from @btm1): Almost all done in the controller using eval ad appending a call to "doCalc" to the JavaScript string. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rf9j8rr4/3/)

```
// In the controller
// this string would really come as the result of an web service call
$scope.javascriptCode = "function doCalc(input) { ... }";

// watch the input variable and call doCalc whenever it changes
$scope.$watch('myInput', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal !== oldVal) {
        // The code we execute is the code we got back, plus a call to
        // doCalc passing in the input.
        var codeToRun = $scope.javascriptCode + " doCalc(" + $scope.scopeInput + ");";

        $scope.myOutput = eval(codeToRun);
    }

<!-- In the view we just have the input -->
<input ng-model="myInput"/>
```

I'm leaning toward solution #2, but I feel like there might be a better solution.

Comment: wrap this in a ng-service, use the service in a ng-controller and then you have ng-repeat by default. on top, watch out what a promise is and does.

Comment: if you are returning a block of js code that's a string you'll need to use eval(yourString) to evaluate the string as js but be ware! eval is evil.

Comment: @bnz wrap what in an ng-service?  The JavaScript code in the question is just a string returned by a web service, not known until the controller requests is.

Comment: @btm1 I don't think eval will work here.  The string is a set of functions, not an expression or statement.

Comment: it will work: go put this in your console:

var f = 'function foo(bar){ alert(bar) ;} foo("hello");';
eval(f);

Comment: u would have to double eval it you'd have to use javascript eval to have it eval to an actual function and then wrap that in $eval to have angular eval it

Comment: @btm1 Thanks for the clarification.  I updated the question with some possible solutions and incorporated your suggestion into #2